# base_link vs base_footprint

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, base-link, base-footprint, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have read that the navigation stacking within ROS requires the use of base_footprint. What is the difference between base_link and base_footprint? How do I know which I should use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291600/base_link-vs-base_footprint/) by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [REP-120](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0120.html#base-footprint):

> base_link
>
> The coordinate frame called `base_link` is rigidly attached to the robot root body. It is recommended to choose the robot waist as its root body. The `base_link` can be attached to the root in any arbitrary position or orientation; for every hardware platform there will be a different place on the base that provides an obvious point of reference. Note that REP 103 [1] specifies a preferred orientation for frames.
>
> base_footprint
>
> The `base_footprint` is the representation of the robot position on the floor. The floor is usually the level where the supporting leg rests, i.e. z = min(l_sole_z, r_sole_z) where l_sole_z and r_sole_z are the left and right sole height respecitvely. The translation component of the frame should be the barycenter of the feet projections on the floor. With respect to the `odom` frame, the roll and pitch angles should be zero and the yaw angle should correspond to the `base_link` yaw angle.
>
> Rationale: `base_footprint` provides a fairly stable 2D planar representation of the humanoid even while walking and swaying with the `base_link`.

[[1] REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions

Also, check out #q208051 and #q94941 for some more explanation.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13